# Regex to split words containing brackets based on group

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following terms which are considered in a group.
`Create` `Set` and `Delete`.

For the below input

```
Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) ) | Delete(Guava)|Set(Orange(Tree))
```

the expected split should be as follows

```
Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) )
Delete(Guava)
Set(Orange(Tree))
```

I could come up with the following regex which is not giving the correct split.

```
(Create|Set|Delete)\(.*\)\s*\|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you use:

```
\s*\|\s*(?=\b(?:Create|Set|Delete)\b)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1pZ6I/5)

---

- `\s*\|\s*` - A literal pipe-symbol surrounded by zero or more spaces (greedy).
- `(?=` - Positive lookahead:

  - `\b` - Word-boundary.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capturing group:

    - `Create|Set|Delete` - Match either of these alternatives literally.
    - `)` - Close non-capturing group.
  - `\b` - Word-boundary.
  - `)` - Close positive lookahead.

**Note:** Just add the other "Associate" and "Disassociate" as alternatives as per your own attempt.

---

In c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"\s*\|\s*(?=\b(?:Create|Set|Delete)\b)";
      string input = "Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) ) | Delete(Guava)|Set(Orange(Tree))";
      string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern, 
                                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                                    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr < result.Length; ctr++) {
         Console.Write("'{0}'", result[ctr]);
         if (ctr < result.Length - 1) 
            Console.Write(", ");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
'Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) )', 'Delete(Guava)', 'Set(Orange(Tree))'
```

Try it over [here](https://repl.it/languages/csharp).

Comment: After using Regex.Split(inputText, expression), the output array contains 1 element which is the inputText  itself.

Comment: @baskar_p, I included some sample code I found to show it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use balanced construct:

```cs
\b(?:Create|Set|Delete)\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3aCreate%7cSet%7cDelete%29%5c%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%5c%28%7c%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%5c%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%5c%29&i=Create%28Apple+%7c+Banana%28Tree%29+%7c+Mango+%28Tree%29+%29+%7c+Delete%28Guava%29%7cSet%28Orange%28Tree%29%29).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:Create|Set|Delete)` - one of the alternatives listed in the non-capturing group
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*` - zero or more occurrences of any one or more chars other than `(` and `)` (see `[^()]+`), or a `(` char (with an empty value pushed onto Group "c" stack), or a `)` char (with a value popped from the Group "c" stack), then
- `(?(c)(?!))` - a conditional failing the match if Group "c" stack is not empty
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/z8PxV4):

```cs
var reg = @"\b(?:Create|Set|Delete)\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)";
var text = "Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) ) | Delete(Guava)|Set(Orange(Tree))";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, reg).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```cs
Create(Apple | Banana(Tree) | Mango (Tree) )
Delete(Guava)
Set(Orange(Tree))
```

Comment: After using Regex.Split(inputText, expression), the output array contains 2 elements which are empty. In the link which you shared, the Split List does not have the output which is expected

Comment: @baskar_p Why do you use `Regex.Split` with a regex meant to *extract*? Use `Regex.Matches(text, @"\b(?:Create|Set|Delete)\((?>[^()]+|(?<c>)\(|(?<-c>)\))*(?(c)(?!))\)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)`

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted @JvdV's answer since it was more elegant IMO. Are there scenarios where your regex handles the input better?

Comment: @baskar_p You cannot compare our solutions in terms of elegancy, they are matching quite different texts and while mine strictly extracts patterns of "one of the words + `(.((..).....)..)` substring", the other one (note the first `\b` word boundary is redundant, `\s*\|\s*(?=(?:Create|Set|Delete)\b)`) only matches  a `|` enclosed with optional whitespace that is directly followed with one of the three words *anywhere* in the string (so if this appears to be inside the nested `(...)` it will get split, too.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation.However, the regex does not give the expected output if I try it in my IDE. I also tried https://repl.it/languages/csharp but the output is 2 empty strings

Comment: @baskar_Copy and paste [**my** code](https://ideone.com/z8PxV4), and click `Run`, it outputs all matches well.

Comment: I agree it runs on ideone. But not on other tools.Not sure if there's issue with the regex engine in the backend

Comment: @baskar_p It works **everywhere**.